# not so simple for me

Tags: adjectives, negation

a. The barbed wire made it not easy to get to the other side.

b. He thought he might make things simple for me. Then he decided he better make them not simple.

c. He thought he might make things simple for me. Then he decided he better make them not so simple.

Which of the above are grammatically correct?

I think they are informal and would work in spoken English, but I would use hyphens (not-easy, not-so-simple) even if I was transcribing a conversation.

There are easy ways to avoid this kind of construct and I would definitely use them in writing. I'd use 'more difficult' or 'harder' in the case of these sentences. Using hyphens seems a better solution to me than using these sentences, because it is as if you are making up 'made-up adjectives'.

Answer (score 2):

None of the examples are grammatically correct. In normal English you cannot add "not" before an adjective to make an adjective with the reverse meaning. This sort of construction is common in texts on logic, but not in normal English. Instead you need to find the correct adjective, for example "difficult" or "hard" instead of "not easy"; "complex" or "hard" instead of "not simple".

Note that in a sentence like "this test is not easy" you must understand "not" as reversing the meaning of "is", not the meaning of "easy". The standard contraction "isn't" for "is not" emphasises this. The sentence means that "this test is easy" is false.

There is an additional problem in your sentences b and c. The expression "he better" should be "he'd better" or "he had better" in both sentences. The word "had" is often reduced so far it is inaudible in spoken English, but it still needs to be written.

I understand your example b to be saying that instead of making things simple for me he decided to make them complicated. If you only mean that he decided not to simplify them the second sentence should be "Then he decided he had better not make them simple." The sentence is still awkward; it would be more idiomatic as "Then he decided he had better not".

In your example c you could change your second sentence to "Then he decided he had better make them less simple." It is still not clear whether he is changing the original things to be less simple, or just not simplifying things as far as he originally intended.